# Select from multiple measurements

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have a bunch of measurements, all starting with `task_runtime.`
i.e.

`task_runtime.task_a
task_runtime.task_b
task_runtime.task_c`

Is there a way to select all of them by a partial measurement name?

I'm using grafana on top of influxdb and I want to display all of these measurements in a single graph, but I don't have a closed list of these measurements.

I thought about something like

`select * from (select table_name from all_tables where table_name like "task_runtime.*")`

But not sure on the influxdb syntax for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a regular expression when specifying measurements in the `FROM` clause as described in the [InfluxDB documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/query_language/data_exploration/#regular-expressions).

For example, in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM /^task_runtime.*/
```

Grafana also supports this and will display all measurements separately.

Comment: I'd like to add that if a database and retention policy name is involved, the query becomes `SELECT * FROM database.autogen././ WHERE ...`, with `/./` being a regex that queries from all measurements